# how to write query to fetch last week records

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to fetch records  from sqlserver2008r2, my query for fetching records for current week is:

```sql
select EmpCode,EventDate1 as EventDate,InTime,
case when OutTime is null then 'N/A' else Outtime end as OutTime from    
TMS_HOURCALC WHERE intime1
  BETWEEN dateadd(dd,(datediff(DD,-53684,getdate())/7)*7,-53684) 
    AND dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7)+7,-53684) 
    and empcode = @empcode
GROUP BY EmpCode, InTime,OutTime, EventDate1,intime1     
order by intime1;
```

Anyone please help me to fetch records for last week only from last sunday to last saturday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a calculation on a column and refering to it in the where clause, will give a terrible performance. This is a much better approach:

```
select EmpCode,EventDate1 as EventDate,InTime,
case when OutTime is null then 'N/A' else Outtime end as OutTime from    
TMS_HOURCALC 
WHERE intime1 >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(DD,-1,getdate())/7)*7-7,-1) 
and intime1 < dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,-1,getdate())/7)*7),-1) 
and empcode = @empcode
GROUP BY EmpCode, InTime,OutTime, EventDate1,intime1     
order by intime1;
```

Comment: Actually I got some performance issues! thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your DB [@@DateFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) is set to 7 (Sunday default) and use [DATEPART()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Try to use:

```
where 
DATEPART(ww, intime1) = DATEPART(ww, GetDate())
and 
YEAR(intime1) = YEAR(GetDate())
```

Comment: this will give performance problems and problems around year change (if the description is correct - from sunday to saturday)